# Multi-Tenant & Multi-Object Permision Suggestions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, identity, asp.net-core

I am looking for suggestions/examples on how to setup permissions for my project.
I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0 with EF Identity 2 (on one server) and will be using IdentityServer4 (secondary server) as my authentication source.

I have multi-tenants (Organizations) that have multiple locations below them.

- Users may have access to one or more Organization.
- Users may have access to one or more locations within the Organization they have access to above.
- Users may have different permissions per organization/permission that they have access to.

To avoid making repeated calls to the server (database), my original plan was to use Claims which I was able to set up as long as the organization only had a single location below it.

Comment: What is your specific software engineering/software design-related question?

Comment: The biggest issue I have run into is I cannot figure out how to set permissions per organization/location per user.  As I said, a user may have Permission to view/create/edit/delete records in one location but in another, they may only be able to view records.

Comment: As I understand it, services like OpenID and EF Identity provide identification and authentication, but not full-blown authorization.  It's up to you to provide Role-Based Access Control through a well thought out database schema.  Have you read this?:  https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Quick-and-Easy-ASPNET-Identity-Multitenancy

Comment: I actually was heading down the path of RoleClaims because it made sense and as long as the organization only had one location everything was fine because permissions (claims) could be linked one-to-one (claim to action).  The issue was when I needed to give a user different permissions for two locations (which are exactly the same but the data is different).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I actually meet Scott on Tuesday and have been trying to discuss this issue with him as well.

Comment: If it's a capability you need, and it's not a capability already present in EF Identity, you'll have to add it as part of your application.

Comment: And by everyone, you mean Robert. :) Don't forget to mark his comment as the right answer. :)